# Mixing websockets and http

Tags: http, websocket, request

When speaking from a conceptual point of view, is it standard practice to mix WebSockets and HTTP requests when making a chat application (or any application that requires real-time communication between devices)?

Imagine a scenario with a client and a server in a chat app. What would be the best approach for connecting and sending data between the client and the server? Would it be using sockets for both sending and receiving or HTTP requests for sending (so the client would get a response and then know if the message was received), and then using WebSocket for only receiving new messages?

Comment: Both would certainly work but if you have a WebSocket connection open for receiving anyway, why would you not just send your chat messages via websocket too?
The approach with mixing both would only make it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not standard practice.

If you need real-time communication between client and server you normally just use a websocket connection and keep that one open. The client can send messages to the server and receive messages through the same connection.
Using HTTP requests for sending messages to the server and receiving new messages via websocket seems odd and just adds unnecessary complexity.

Now if your server has some endpoints to subscribe for real-time data e.g. a chat room and endpoints for getting information you don't necessary want to subscribe to e.g. information about a certain user, than you can use the appropriate protocol for each endpoint